# CPU time of process in Windows PerfMon

Tags: perfmon

I am trying to get the CPU usage by specific process

Like in the below image the CPU column shows the CPU usage by specific process
But did not get similar counter in perfmon

I tried using \Process\% Processor Time but the value shown in PerfMon are different.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in Advance

**Solved from Below Post:**

Didn't find any direct way from perfmon so decided to write code for that and it worked.

[Calculating process cpu usage from Process.TotalProcessorTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756454/calculating-process-cpu-usage-from-process-totalprocessortime)

Comment: In perfmon, there is a table of counters shown under the graph. Can you please post a snapshot of the complete table after adding `\Process\% Processor Time`?

Comment: Hadi Baris image added in the post

Answer (score 0):

From the perfmon snapshot, there are two counters and the graphs of both counters have the same color. That's why the result is confusing. You should either uncheck the first counter (which represents the total processor time) or change the color of one of the counters by right clicking on the counter and accessing its properties.